# set field to a value after DetailView is updated

Tags: asp.net

After the DetailsView is updated and clicked the Update Command button on the DetailView; I want to set one of the fields to “Complete”.  What am I doing wrong here?  Pls. help.
here is my code behind:

```
 Protected Sub Test(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemUpdated
        If IsPostBack Then
            Dim TextBox7 As TextBox = TryCast(DetailsView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).FindControl("TextBox7"), TextBox)
            TextBox7.Text = "Complete"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method and got it to work.

```
Protected Sub PageDetailsView_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)
    If Me.PageDetailsView.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly] Then  
        If e.CommandName.Equals("GenerateModifiedDate", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then 
            Dim modifiedDateLabel As Label = TryCast(Me.PageDetailsView.FindControl("ModifiedDateLabel"), Label)
            modifiedDateLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        End If 
    Else
        If e.CommandName.Equals("GenerateModifiedDate", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
           Dim modifiedDateTextbox As TextBox = TryCast(Me.PageDetailsView.FindControl("ModifiedDateTextbox"), TextBox)
           modifiedDateTextbox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        End If 
    End If
End Sub
```